# Big project, huge lack of test coverage, how would you approach this?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, functional-testing, behat, mink

So i have this huge SF2 project, which is luckily pretty 'OK' written. Services are there, background jobs are there, no god classes, it's testable--but, i never gotten any further than just unit-testing stuff, so the question is basically, where do i start taking this further.

The project consists of SF2 and all the yada yada, Doctrine2, Beanstalkd, Gaufrette, some other abstractions--its fine.
The one problem it has is some gluecode in controllers here and there, but i don't see it as a big problem since functional tests are going to me the main focus.
The infrastructure is setup pretty ok as well, its covered by docker so CI is going to work out well also.

But it has basically gotten too large to manually test any longer, so i want full functional coverage on short notice, and let the unit-testing grow over time. (Gonna dive into the isolated objects as they need future adjustments and build test for them in due course)

So i got the unit-testing covered, thats going to need to grow over time, but i want to make some steps towards the functional testing to get some quick gains on the testing dep. YESTERDAY.

My plan as of now is use Behat and Mink for this, the tests are going to be huge, so i might as well want to have it set as stories instead of code. Behat also seem to have a extension for Symfony' BrowserKit.
There are plenty of services and external things happening, but they are all isolated by services, so i can mock them through the test environment service config i guess.
**Please some advice here if there is as better way**

I'm also going to need fixtures, i'm using Alice for generating some fixtures so far, seems nice together with the doctrine extension, don't think there are "better" options on this one.

How should i test external services? Im mocking things as a Facebook service, but i also want to really test it to some test account, is this advisable? I know that this goes beyond its scope, the service has to be mocked and tested in every way possible to "ensure its working" according to the purist. But in the end of the day it still breaks because of some API key or other problem in the connection, which i cant afford really. **So please advice here also**

All your suggestions to use other tools are welcome ofcourse, and especially if there is a good book that covers my story.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you brought up behat, I was going to suggest the same thing.

I would consider starting with your most business critical pieces; unit test the extremely important business logic and use behat on the rest.

For the most part, I would create stubs for your services that have expected output for expected input.  That way you can create failures based on specific input.  You can override your services in your test config.

Another approach would be to do very thin functional testing where you make GET requests to all of your endpoints and look for 200's.  This is a very quick way to make sure that your pages are at least loading.  From there, you can start writing tests for your POST endpoints and expanding your suite further with more detailed test cases.